# Is it ok for sites to copy questions and inject advertising?

Tags: support

I was searching Google for a solution to one of my problems and I came across a solution to a [question I posted on this site a couple hours ago](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149653/how-do-i-override-a-service-endpoint-provided-by-a-module-in-a-feature)--

Except it was a different site:
http://drupalanswerscm.blogspot.ca/2015/02/how-do-i-override-service-endpoint.html

What's the SE policy on this kind of thing?

EDIT: Here's another advertising-filled site that ranks higher than Drupal Answers in Google:

http://dluat.com/how-can-i-implement-a-non-crud-function-in-hook_service_resources/

Answer (score 4):

In short, I think it's allowed as long as your clear about where the content comes from. That doesn't appear to be the case here, so I think the site should be reported.

Latest, as far as I'm aware, policy:
[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

Comment: Yes, that is the latest policy.